# Adverbs for Dirty (Dirtily?)

Tags: adverbs

It is common to simply use 'dirty' as the adverb here, ex: He talks dirty.

Other resources say that the adverb is dirtily! I do not believe I've *ever* heard this used... is it correct?

Comment: dirtily is alright, although you should look up some synonyms for dirt.

Comment: What about 'and I looked at him so dirtily'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Dirtily* is the adverb while *dirty* is used as an adjective or verb. However, *to talk dirty* is an informal phrase and is always used this way.

> [**talk dirty**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0228670#m_en_gb0228670)
>    *informal* talk about sex in a coarse or salacious way.

I assume that you wouldn't want to talk about talking dirty in a formal context anyway, so *talk dirty* should be fine.

Comment: Unless you are a geologist, agriculturalist, or dry cleaner. Then "talk dirty to me" can have less salacious meanings. :^)

Answer (score 6):

*Dirtily* is correct, but it does sound a bit clunky. A few alternative adverbs: foully, uncleanly, shamefully, basely, vulgarly, coarsely.

Comment: "Talk foully to me." - It just doesn't roll off the tongue.

Comment: @user6223: True. In many contexts, "talk dirty" would be the way to go despite its not being grammatically correct. :)

Comment: you sure? [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dirty?show=1&t=1300428587) says "dirty (adv): in a dirty manner: as a: deceptively, underhandedly <fight dirty>, b: indecently <talk dirty>"

Answer (score 0):

"Dirtily" is the correct form for the adverb.   Think of it this way,  "As the miner emerged from days working in the coal mine, he was dressed so DIRTILY I barely recognized him".

Comment: *Dirtyily* !  Surely some mistake.

Comment: No.  Take the time to know what you're talking about.  The proper adverb for "dirty" is "dirtily".  The proper adverb for "pretty" is "prettily".   It's really quite simple if you'd take the time to learn the English language.

Comment: *The proper adverb for "dirty" is "dirtily".*  I concur.  Which is why I find the first word of your answer rather odd.